# Cross-referencing functions in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, forward-declaration, cross-reference

I'm getting warnings in my Common Lisp code due to cross-referencing functions it doesn't matter terribly much as the code runs just fine, however I'm worried it could somehow lead to future errors.

So say we have this condition:

```
(defun a (x)
  ...
  (b x))

(defun b (y)
  (a y)
  ...)
```

So as you can see, `a` is dependent on `b`, and `b` is dependent on `a`, so as you might imagine, evaluating this file will cause a warning saying `b` isn't defined.

So my question is: What's the idiomatic way of dealing with this? Is it somehow possible to forward-declare `b` so `a` is aware of it? Or should I just leave it be and trust the interpreter to know what it's doing?

Comment: Can the function `a` take a function (`b`) as an argument? What behavior are you trying to implement in `a` and `b` and how would the execution not go on forever? Maybe a `cond` inside a single common function would be cleaner

Comment: but the point of multiple functions is to spread out the code base, so it's not just one single god-function